# clear ms word add-in global variables in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, add-in

I developed a plugin for MS Word in VB.NET.
I defined a number of global variables. After running the plugin and finishing it, the values of the variables remain and become problematic in the next run.
How can I clear or delete these values?

Comment: You will need to provide more insight into your add-in. Is a vsto or document level addin? Does it have a ribbon, what does it do? What is the purpose of these global variables?

Comment: Is a VSTO and has a ribbon.

Comment: A ribbon is loaded when the addin loads, gets initialized and then shows the ribbon, waiting for user input. It is not clear what you mean with 'running the plugin'. Is it the loading of the ribbon, is it responding to user input, is it responding to an event? And then, what does it do? If you persist in not giving the right information, then you will not get the support you are looking for. I suggest you start with the 'how to ask a good question': https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask